# Colocar um texto fixo dentro de uma imagem - responsiva com Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando colocar um texto e um botão dentro de uma imagem, porém não estou conseguindo manter eles de forma responsiva.

```css
.dados {
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 0;
}

.text {
    font-family: "Arial Bold", Arial;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="position-relative">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
          <div class="position-absolute dados">
            <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Eu quero que essas informações fiquem dentro da imagem, no canto inferior direito.
Alguém sabe fazer isso, de forma que se mantenha responsiva?

Answer (score 0):

Cara basicamente o que ficou faltando foi colocar a classe `w-100` nas imagens para elas ocuparem no máximo `100%` da largura do próprio `container pai`. Assim elas não "encavalam" umas sobre as outras. E a outra coisa foi colocar o *Grid* responsivo, vc usou só `col-4` no `container pai`, porem para telas menores que `600px` já começava a ficar ruim, então coloquei `col-12 com-md-4` na coluna, assim até temas `MD` fica em 3 colunas e abaixo disso fica 1 coluna por linha

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
.dados {
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

.text {
    font-family: "Arial Bold", Arial;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 my-2">
            <div class="position-relative">
                <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
                <div class="position-absolute dados">
                    <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 my-2">
            <div class="position-relative">
                <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
                <div class="position-absolute dados">
                    <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4 my-2">
            <div class="position-relative">
                <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
                <div class="position-absolute dados">
                    <h3 class="text-right text">Testes?<br>Teste teste teste teste</h3>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">veja detalhes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```